# introduce <Tab> in new line while creating a block for python files in vim

Tags: python, vim, vi

I want to introduce a ***tab*** character in the new line for creating a new block in vim for python files.

**Example**

when I write

```
if(a < 5):
```

and press ***Enter***, the cursor should come in next line with a ***tab*** after **if** in vertical alignment from the above line. Something like this

```
if(a < 5):  
    a = 5
```

I have configured my .vimrc file like this

```
set nu
set autoindent
set tabstop=4
syntax enable
set showmatch
colorscheme gruvbox 
set bg=dark

"automatically creates a block after :
autocmd FileType python inoremap :<CR> :<CR><Tab>
```

**Note:**
**1)** Last line, I have written for the intended purpose mentioned in my question.
**2)** autoindent is set.
**3)** I dont want to use any plugin.

**Problem I am facing:**

When I press **Enter** after **:** , in addition to ***tab***, one extra space is also created which creates wrong indentation.

Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: People usually want to avoid <Tab> char in source code. Why you want it?

Comment: i just want perfect indentation. i used to code in java where i used tabs for indenting. just old habits.

Comment: python ftplugin will handle indentation. You don't have to the mapping

Comment: i actually want to configure .vimrc myself. i figured it shouldnt be that hard

Comment: @Manya Intelligent indentation based on the current syntax is actually not that simple, which is why Vim has 127 lines of code in the python indent plugin that figures it out for you...

Comment: got that @DanLowe. thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're trying to do this is the hard way. There's a filetype plugin and a Python syntax type and it already knows what to do.

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

And don't use `set autoindent`. It's not very intelligent, it just copies the indent from the previous line. It's the opposite of what you're trying to do.

Files ending in `.py` should automatically get the right settings. If you need to force the current syntax type in a buffer, you can do that with

```
:set filetype=python
```

If you want to use tabs instead of spaces,

```
" Globally
set noexpandtab

" Python only
autocmd FileType python set noexpandtab
```

However, I'll note that using tabs in Python is not recommended and goes against published best practices (see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

Lastly I'll mention that "plugin" is just a Vim term. All of this ships with Vim by default, this does not create a third-party dependency.

Comment: actually i dont want to use any plugin. want to do it on my own by configuring .vimrc file. i should probably write this in the question

Comment: Thanks @Dan Lowe. i got it and changed my config and its working like a charm. thanks a lot. And just one more question loosely related to the above question. where can i learn more about configuring the .vimrc file and gaining in-dept knowledge of vim. and thanks again . :)

Comment: @Manya Drew Neil's stuff at http://vimcasts.org/ and book Practical Vim are good - you can also look at https://vi.stackexchange.com/ which is a stackoverflow sister site dedicated to vi & vim. Also `:help` in Vim itself is a very thorough resource for documentation.

Comment: @Manya More advanced, if you are interested in learning vimscript (writing your own vim modules), https://github.com/tpope is a treasure trove of very good vim plugins to learn from.